Why is this not in Konjunktiv II tense?
This sentence appears in the Der Anschlag, translated from S. King's 11/22/63.

Nur waren auch hier die Schaufenster eingeworfen worden, und was in dem Geschäft auf Lager gewesen sein mochte, war längst verschwunden.

Why is this not

...und was in dem Geschäft auf Lager gewesen sein möchte,...

or

...und was in dem Geschäft auf Lager möchte gewesen sein,...

The corresponding English in the original is

Except these windows were also broken, and any goods that might have been inside were long gone.


Möchte, although grammatically the past subjunctive of mögen, is basically a verb in its own right signifying want.

Ich möchte nicht der Luther gewesen sein. (Kolb, Die Schaukel; via DWDS corpora)
I wouldn't want to have been Luther.

Mögen, when it is not past subjunctive, can express a possibility.

Mag sein.
Maybe. It's possible.

Or express an assumption.

Es mögen so um die vierzig Leute gewesen sein.
There may have been about forty people.

It is clear that in was in dem Geschäft auf Lager gewesen sein mochte, the intended meaning is that of possibility or assumption; therefore the past subjunctive cannot be used.
The modality is so weak in contexts such as these that it is often not expressed by a verb; auch (immer) (ever) is sufficient.

(Der neue Präsident,)
wer auch immer es ist.
whoever that is.
wer auch immer es sein mag.
whoever that may be.


The reason the question arose for me is related to the statement in Hammers German Grammar and Usage, page 347,

"The main use of the past subjunctive and all the Konjunkiv II forms is to indicate an unreal condition or a possibility."

And as stated by David Vogt, the intended meaning is that of a possibility. So why not Konjunktiv II? Apparently the reason is that mögen is idiomatically used in this respect. As Hammar states on page 377,

"There are idomatic phrases expressing possibility, 'Das mag wohl sein,'"


and, "A few phrases with möchte convey a doubt or a supposition, 'Ich möchte meinen, dass...'"

So my conclusion is that this verb is applied idiomatically and the usual rules for using Konjunctiv II cannot be applied.

There is no Konjunktiv in the German sentence, but it's rather plain Präteritum.
While you might "feel" a semantic irrealis which is in the basic semantics of the verb, so there's no grammatical one in addition to it. (And that's, by the way, exactly like with the English verb "might").
